# How to filter data on a list according to multiple parameters in Java?

Tags: java, list, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a list of *GroupOffices*

```
List<GroupOffice> officesOfTheGroup;
```

I want to search whether the id is not equal to *groupOffice.getId* (Long value) but the label is *groupOffice.getLabel* (String)  and assign it to a boolean. The below code is working good, but is there any better approach instead of go through all items with for loop ?

```
 public GroupOfficeDto saveGroupOffice(GroupOfficeDto groupOfficeDto) {     
            List<GroupOffice> officesOfTheGroup = //some list from db..
            for (GroupOffice go : officesOfTheGroup) {
                if ((!go.getId().equals(groupOfficeDto.getId())) && go.getLabel().equals(groupOfficeDto.getLabel())) {
                    return groupOfficeDto;
                }
        return null:
}
```

Or how can I use stream ? If so, is using stream is better approach for it ?

*Note:* I am using Java8

Comment: *I want to search whether a id equals 5 but the label is not London and assign it to a boolean* your code does the opposite.

Comment: I'm confused.  The code you present seems to perform a test opposite to the one you describe.

Comment: thanks for comments I have edited question. the code is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need boolean value you can do:

```
boolean b = officesOfTheGroup.stream()
    .anyMatch(office -> !office.getId().equals(5) && office.getLabel().equals("London"))
```

Comment: what is 'office' here? its not defined ?

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn sorry, it's lambda argument. Just edited

Comment: when I use some dto.getId and to.getLabel instead of London and 5, it is giving error about it must be final.. How can I use parameter instead of these hardcoded values?

Comment: variable used in lambda expression must be final or effectively final... error is this.

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn see [effective final](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-is-effectively-final-variable-of.html) explanation

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn do you assign any value to `groupOfficeDto` inside your method before loop ?

Comment: yes I have assigned as you said effective final and solved

Answer (score 2):

> is there any better approach instead of go through all items with `for` loop ?

Notably, your code *does not* go through all the items if it finds an acceptable one before reaching the end of the list.  But if you have only the list to work with, then there is no alternative to being prepared to check every list element.  As to whether to use a `for` loop, I think that's just fine.

> Or how can I use stream ? If so, is using stream is better approach for it ?

It is indeed pretty fashionable these days to use streams, and although they seem to be used more than I think they should, yours is not an unreasonable use case.  You might write it like this:

```
public GroupOfficeDto saveGroupOffice(GroupOfficeDto groupOfficeDto) {     
    List<GroupOffice> officesOfTheGroup = //some list from db..
    Integer officeId = groupOfficeDto.getId();
    String officeLabel = groupOfficeDto.getLabel();

    return officesOfTheGroup.stream()
            .filter(o -> !o.getId().equals(officeId))
            .anyMatch(o -> o.getLabel().equals(officeLabel))
        ? groupOfficeDto : null;
}
```

Particularly relevant here is use of the `.anyMatch()` terminal operation, because it allows stream processing to finish as soon as the result is determined, like your `for` loop, rather than processing the entire stream.  Also note that the ID and Label against which you are comparing the offices are extracted and stored in variables before the stream expression.  This allows them to be "effectively final", as is necessary for them to appear in the lambdas in the stream.  It's also slightly more efficient to do it this way, instead of retrieving the same objects from the DTO over and over again -- for the `for` loop case, too.

Do note that the stream version is not much simpler than the loop version, and not much easier to read, either.  I don't personally see much advantage for either one over the other.

Comment: oh there is an error: on "o.getLabel()" in any match, o is not resolved variable error.. can you fix the error please ?

Comment: @ChrisGarsonn, I think you probably could have figured it out yourself, but it's poor form for me to leave an error in my code.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public GroupOfficeDto saveGroupOffice(GroupOfficeDto groupOfficeDto) {
    ...     
    List<GroupOffice> result = officesOfTheGroup.stream()
        .filter(it -> it.getLabel().equals(groupOfficeDto.getLabel()))
        .filter(it -> !it.getId().equals(groupOfficeDto.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ...
}
```

Comment: when I use some dto.getId and to.getLabel instead of London and 5, it is giving error about it must be final.. How can I use parameter instead of these hardcoded values?